# IVP using Laplace transform.

Tags: laplace-transform

For the equation $′′+9=\delta(−4)$, with $(0)=0$ and $′(0)=0$;  where the $g(t)$ is the step function.

Taking the Laplace of the left sides gives: $L\{\}\{ s^2 +9 \}$.

For the left side, from the table, I see that $\delta(−4)$ is transformed into 
$\ \frac{e^{-4s}}{s}\ $.

Moving everything to the right side to solve I have to take the inverse of  : $\ \frac{e^{-4s}}{s} \{\frac{1}{s^2 +9}\}$.

However, looking at the solution notes I have I'm seeing that the inverse should not include that "S" under the $\ \ e^{-4s}\ $.  As in the solution just took the inverse of $e^{-4s} \{\frac{1}{s^2 +9}\}$ and got

$\frac{1}{3} U_4(t) \sin(3(t-4))$ as an answer.

Does that "$S$" get factored out along with the $e^{-4s}$ while we are focused on transforming the other expression or does it get distributed through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the laplace transform of  $\delta(−4)$ is $e^{-4s} $.

$$
L^{-1}[ e^{-c s}L(f)]=u(t-c) f(t-c)$$

Hen ce 
$$\frac{1}{3} L^{-1}[ e^{-4 s}\frac{3}{s^2 +9}]=u(t-4) \sin(3(t-4))$$

Comment: I realized that this is a delta function and not the U notation used for regular step functions.  Thats where my confusion was.